# Algebraic dependence of $xy, xz$ and $ yz$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and their symmetry

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

1. Show that $ xy, xz, yz \in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ are algebraically dependent over  $\mathbb{C}$ by finding a polynomial they satisfy. Is there a more general method or approach that I should take when looking for this kind of algebraic dependence?
2. Does the symmetry between $xy, xz $ and $ yz $ imply that the polynomial they satisfy must be symmetric? How to prove it without explicitly finding the polynomial?

Comment: What about this: $f(xy,xz,yz)=0\implies f(x,y,z)=0$? If $f(x,y,z)=\sum a_{ijk}x^iy^jz^k$, then $f(xy,xz,yz)=\sum a_{ijk}x^{i+j}y^{i+k}z^{j+k}$ and $$i+j=i'+j',i+k=i'+k',j+k=j'+k'\iff i=i',j=j',k=k'.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not algebraically dependent over $\mathbb{C}$!  Probably the easiest way to see this is to think about the subfield $\mathbb{C}(xy,xz,yz)\subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y,z)$ which they generate, since using division we can isolate one variable at a time.  Notice that $(xy)(xz)/(yz)=x^2$ is in this subfield, and so by symmetry so are $y^2$ and $z^2$.  But $x^2,y^2,$ and $z^2$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$, so the $\mathbb{C}(xy,xz,yz)$ has transcendence degree at least $3$ over $\mathbb{C}$.  It follows that the three generators $xy,yz,xz$ must be algebraically independent.

Comment: Alternatively, you can prove the algebraic independence of $yz,zx,xy $ simply by showing that any two distinct monomials in $yz,zx,xy$ will be distinct also as monomials in $x,y,z$.